# Isolated group of users who believe that a technology/tool is vastly superior to alternatives

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

Consider a group of users of a given technology (e.g. an obscure programming language) who think that such technology is superior to any other technology, and whose opinion disagrees with the mainstream opinion.

What adjectives can be used to describe such groups of people?

Comment: iPhone users...

Comment: Too broad. Informed / misguided.

Comment: Conservative, close-minded, unadventurous.

Comment: @HotLicks also consider *correct, superior, discerning ... ;)*  Josh, a lot of adjectives could fit. Can you narrow down what you want any further? Are you looking to be rude or neutral? Are you looking for http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SmugLispWeenie or *unorthodox, nonconformists, mavericks, eccentrics, rebels, dissidents, outsiders...*, or *smug, insular, ignorant, dismissive, narrow-minded, obsessive*...

Answer (score 3):

zealots is the first phrase that comes to mind

Answer (score 2):

Since they consider it superior to any other without any substantial reason as to why, they may be elitists, or showing signs of [elitism](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elitism).

> 1:  leadership or rule by an elite
>
> 2:  the selectivity of the elite; especially :  snobbery (elitism in choosing new members)  - Mirriam-Webster

Snobbery or being a [snob](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Snob) would also fit.

> Anyone who thinks they are better than someone else based upon superficial factors. - UrbanDictionary

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're looking for a word which describes someone as **inflexible**, **skeptic** and refusing to change one's views or notion about something. It could be **HERETIC**, a person who differs from what is generally accepted. If someone sticks to outdated, stereotyped choices, it could be **archaic**. But more specifically I would suggest " **Luddite** ", which means someone who is opposed to technological change.

Comment: I wouldn't pick Luddite; fans of obscure programming languages often consider themselves more technologically advanced, more willing to learn something new, and sometimes consider the rest of the programming world is lagging behind from an unwillingness to handle anything new and different. (Assuming 'obscure language' doesn't just mean 'old language').

Answer (score 1):

They could be purists ... what is the purpose of the obscure language? ... Or they could be dinosaurs ... or they could be [insert name of obscure programming language here] snobs. Again, depends on the purpose and EFFECTIVENESS of the obscure language.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going for something that most people would recognize, I'd go with public wireless's suggestion of **zealots**.

... but if you're willing to accept slang, then you might consider **fanboi**.  You can also use **fanboy**, which is typically considered to be less condescending.

Answer (score 1):

Because, although the group you seek to describe is secular, their defining characteristics have strong religious overtones, you might consider the following:

> **TRUE BELIEVER** *noun*:
>
> **1**. a person who professes absolute belief in something
>
> **2**. a zealous supporter of a particular cause
>
> See, Merriam-Webster [“**true believer**”](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/true%20believer)
>
> **Devotee** *noun*: plural noun: ***devotees***
>
> a person who is very interested in and enthusiastic about someone or something.
>   "*a devotee of classical music*"
>
> *synonyms*: enthusiast, fan, lover, aficionado, admirer;
>
> "*a devotee of rock music*"
>
> • a strong believer in a particular religion or god.
>
> "*devotees of Krishna*"
>
> *synonyms*: follower, adherent, supporter, advocate, disciple, votary, member, stalwart, fanatic, zealot
>
> see, Google.com [“**devotee**”](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=devotee+de&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=devotee+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0l5.0.0.10.984911...........0.FTMkWtARyL4&gws_rd=ssl)